# How to properly restart service onResume

Tags: java, android

On my Service(Service1) I have **onCreate()** & **onDestroy()** methods,

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);

    super.onDestroy();

}
```

After clicking the home button(user is now on device home scren) the **onDestroy()** method will be triggered after x minutes, When I open the app again I want to restart the service so the **onCreate()** will be called again, so I tried  this code on my activity's onResume()

```
    stopService(new Intent(this, Service1.class));
    startService(new Intent(this, Service1.class));
```

And it fixed the issue, the **onCreate()** is called again, but is this the right way of restarting it after **onDestroy()**? (Some says this will cause issues), I saw some articles that we should use **onStartCommand()** or **startForegroundService()**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alriht. Let's discuss some points about behaviour of services.

**Before Oreo(Android 8):**

If you are using startService or stopService it will work fine on the devices below Oroe(Android 8). Starting from Oreo google has implemented mechanism so that we must need to start foreground service along with service to inform users that some background task is running so with foreground service we must need to add notification to notify users that there is some task running in background. Let's suppose playing music, downloading file or uploading dat etc.

**What if we don't start foreground service on Oreo or later Versions:**

If we dont start foreground service right after starting service then our operating system will kill service with in 5 seconds.

**Background task **recommendation**:**

If you only need to do background task then you need to implement WorkManager. Workmanagers are more flexible, backward compatible and easy to handle. We don't need to start workmanagers on device reboot like service they restart itself and depends on implementation they can run till your application life. We can also add constraint like internet connectivity or battery etc. So, we can save our battery too.
Check [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager?gclid=Cj0KCQjw2tCGBhCLARIsABJGmZ6QbzgM1vAyoZSa5XDKc62i8EfU-bzSvTAiQlVUbLLrJT8As6BQysQaAg91EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) to read more about workmanager.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so if I use this foreground service, it wont kill my service after x minutes, Thanks

Comment: I got this issue only some devices of oppo and vivo that service stops after x minutes even if we use foreground. Then the only way is to restart service. But else then these devices which are ore or above orea i didn't face this scenario that service stops while using foreground.

Comment: About services oppo's behavour was weird. Serice stops after x minutes and again starts after x minutes. I then do some R&D and got that there were some restrictions from OS owners. So i started using work manager and i love it because we don't need to care about if we are on oreo or below oreo. Work manager handles every thing itself.

Comment: Okay okay, Ill try it now. Thanks

Comment: so youre saying I can use 'work manager' class to replace my Service? and It'll do the same work of Service?

Comment: Yes, it would be much better.

Comment: For now, I did the foreground service, and yes it solved my problem, the service doesn't stop after x minutes, I need a lot of adjustments in work manager but I'll do more research about that in the future and use it, Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Nice to work with you. For appriciation and for others too please don't forget to upvote or mark it as best if you feel it as best.